# How to fetch text from pdf to further proceed with question answer based model from the same document?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, cnn, computer-vision

To illustrate the above title.

*Suppose you have a pdf document, which is basically scanned from hardcopy, now there are set of fixed questions to answer from the document itself. 
For an example a document contains a contract of land, now the set of fixed questions be "who is the seller?" "what is price of the asset? ", document has referred to this answers probably 2-3 times, as a human it's a simple task.*

How to automate this?

Comment: It's not so simple task for a machine, a top view of the pipeline would something like this, steps: 1) localize text 2) recognize text 3) run your further processing via Q&A it It's tough one!

Comment: I think you mean an OCR task, for example:
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/

Comment: Hey. @Aditya I understand, it has got some complexity. That's why I am using this forum. Please can you share your inputs at any of the process mentioned?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: Follow the instructions of the installation process of tesseract-ocr. Once you installed it, use it to recognize the text from the scanned document. In the recognized text try to searching the relevant terms ("seller", "price"). Next to these terms you should find your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pypdf2 to extract text from pdf.

```
import PyPDF2

with open('sample.pdf','rb') as pdf_file, open('sample_output.txt', 'w') as text_file:
    read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
    number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
    for page_number in range(number_of_pages):   # use xrange in Py2
        page = read_pdf.getPage(page_number)
        print('Page No - ' + str(1 + read_pdf.getPageNumber(page)))
        page_content = page.extractText()
        text_file.write(page_content)
```

Comment: I will try this extraction process, after this can you point me at the process to fetch answer from the context?
I believe it can be acheived through question answer NLP based model, please do share your views too. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using OCR engines like `pytesseract`. Once the text has been extracted you can either use custom NLP rules for framing the questions and their answers or use a Question Answering model which will do this for you. There are many such models like `Layoutlm` series. `Huggingface` hosts many such models.

Also do not use `PyPDF2` as it is not that robust when compared to `pytesseract`. I tried it and it only works on certain pdfs.

**Cheers!**